# cant create a relationship between application user table and my tables

Tags: entity

I'm using entity framework code first.  The below keeps kicking out the unable to determine the principal end of an association.  Basically I can't figure out how to get one to many relationships between the auto generated identity table and my own tables with code first.

```
public class applicationUser : Identity
{

public User user {get;set;}

}

//and then a dependant class called User

public class User
{
public in Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("Identity")]
public string IdentityId {get;set;}
public ApplicationUser Identity {get;set;}

public string UserPicLocation {get;set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using [ForeignKey()] wrong. The value of [ForeignKey()] should be the name of the property that contains the key of the referenced object.
You should also mark the property that contains the key in the referenced object as the private key with [Key]
Try this:

```
public class applicationUser : Identity
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User user {get;set;}

}

and then another class called User

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public string IdentityId {get;set;}
    public ApplicationUser Identity {get;set;}

    public string UserPicLocation {get;set;}    
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks.  I tried that previously but the same error presented itself.  In fact, I tried all three methods of defining the foreign key as described on this page:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Tried this too:

    public class applicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
      
    public User user {get;set;}

    }



    //this is the dependant table

    public class User
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("Identity")]
        public string IdentityId {get;set;}
        public ApplicationUser Identity {get;set;}
 
        public string UserPicLocation {get;set;}    
    }

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting the primary key as both the primary and foreign key in the dependant table